# Why is this nonstatic member class consider an Adapter?

Tags: java

I'm currently reading Effective Java 3rd edition (Item 24 - page 112) and I'm confused.

I need to quote a small portion from the book for context sake.

Why the class `MyIterator` is an Adapter? I don't see it adapting anything or I misunderstand?
Thanks & sorry for the grammar error.

Quote from the book:

> One common use of a nonstatic member class is to define an **Adapter**
> [Gamma95] that allows an instance of the outer class to be viewed as
> an instance of some unrelated class. For example, implementations of
> the `Map` interface typically use nonstatic member classes to implement
> their collection views, which are returned by Map’s `keySet`, `entrySet`,
> and values methods. Similarly, implementations of the collection
> interfaces, such as `Set` and `List`, typically use nonstatic member
> classes to implement their iterators:

```java
// Typical use of a nonstatic member class
public class MySet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> {
  ... // Bulk of the class omitted
  @Override public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new MyIterator();
  }
  private class MyIterator implements Iterator<E> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call any of those things adapters myself. I also don't know why Bloch keeps saying 'nonstatic member class' when the specific Java term is 'inner class'. I'm not his greatest fan frankly.

Comment: Agreed. Sounds like a very misleading book.

Comment: @user207421 So what should I do now? Just ignore it? :(

Comment: You should make up your own mind about what you've been told here.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of the Adapter pattern from [Gamma95] is:

> Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn't otherwise because of incompatible interfaces.

So if you were to have a class that expects an `Iterator` you can pass a `MyIterator` instance to it by calling the `iterator()` method. `MyIterator` is considered an adapter as it makes `MySet` look like an `Iterator`.
In this case it's just an implementation choice to use an inner class for the implementation. `AbstractSet` requires the `iterator()` method to be implemented.

Comment: So that's what he mean when he wrote: `that allows an instance of the outer class to be viewed as an instance of some unrelated class.`? In short, its just his preference? Thanks!

Comment: I do not agree that it makes the Set look like an Iterator. The method provides a new iterator object that operates on the set. It isn't the same thing. Classically an Adapter in the GoF book is a wrapper around one object that implements a different interface style. Well-known examples in Java include Apache Commons Logging.

Comment: So your wrapping a `Set` with an `Iterator`. I don't understand the distinction you are trying to make. The Iterator is a delegate object that forwards requests to the set as per the GoF book.